# Vim, Find and replace `^(.*)` with `^{.*}`

Tags: vim, regex

I'm trying to find and replace `caret open_parentheses some_content close_parentheses` (i.e.`^(.*)`) with `caret open_curly_bracket the_same_content close_curly_bracket` (i.e. `^{.*}` but I have issues.

1) I do not understand how to preserve the matched wildcard content `.*`

2) I do not see how to formulate the 
escape sequence to specify curly brackets and parentheses.

I have been going through [this](http://vimregex.com/) page for quite a bit and have attempted the following

```
%s/^(*)/^{*} /gc
%s/^(.*)/^{.*} /gc
%s/^/(.*/)/^{.*} /gc
```

Comment: What carrots? Did you mean caret?

Comment: Yes i did mean caret!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of those characters have special functionality depending if an escape character precedes them.  This depends on the character whether an escape sequence preceding the character with special functionality utilises it (i.e. a `^` executes special functionality, a `\^` does not, where a `(` does *not* execute special functionality, and a `\(` does.

The expression you are looking for is as follows

```
s/\^(\([^)])\))/\^\{\1\}/g
```

The expression literally state, match a **caret** followed by an **open_parenthesis** followed by **any character except a close_parenthesis** followed by a **close_parenthesis** and replace with a a **caret** followed by an **open_curly_bracket** followed by the content found when searching for **any_character_except a close_parenthesis** (i.e. the content between `\(` and `\)`) followed by a **close_curly_bracket**

Note: other approaches exist as well

Comment: How do I say the first occurrence of the of the ')' close_parentheses?

Comment: The regex works but matched the last close_parentheses before the newline character.

Comment: There are two ways to do that. One is to replace `*` by `\{-}` to match as few `.` as possible. See `:help /\{-`. The other is to replace `.` by `[^)]` to match anything *not* a `)`. See `:help /[]`.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about the greedy match thing. Thanks @kinokijuf for editing my answer!

Comment: @fluffy but i only corrected several typos

Comment: @kinokijuf Huh! Well someone else must have much more thoroughly edited my answer before you did. For some reason I can't seem to find the edit log... strange. My answer as it stands now has very little resemblance with what I wrote yesterday.

Comment: Ah, looks like it was the person who asked this question who did the majority of the editing: http://superuser.com/suggested-edits/13410  Well, then. Thanks @rudolph9!

Comment: @fluffy couldn't have figured it out without you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really looking for the caret character?
The caret usually means to start looking for the pattern at the beginning of a line.

Assuming you are...

some text ^( more text ) and more ^( more text ) and more

--AND-- you what it changed to:

some text ^{ more text } and more ^{ more text } and more

Then, use:

:s-\^(([^)]+))-^{\1}-gc

```
:s      the substitute command
-       start pattern, use - instead of / for clarity
\^      look for the ^ char, need to escape
(       followed by (
\(      start capture
[^)]\+  one or more chars except )
\)      end capture
)       followed by )
-       start replace, use - instead of / for clarity
^{      replace ^( with ^{
\1      replace with the captured text
}       replace ) with }
-       start flags, use - instead of / for clarity
gc      confirm replace for each occurance in the line
```

If you want the search and replace to span the whole file, then use:

:%s-\^(([^)]+))-^{\1}-gc

The % means the whole file.

Comment: My assumption in this question is that he's looking to replace regexps with other regexps, using a regexp. Always tricky. :)